# ASP.NET docker container starts and then immediately stops

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net, docker

I followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx) blog post to get an asp.net application running in a docker container, but straight after running my container it stops. When I look at the logs for the container, this is all I get:

```
2015-05-28T03:46:56.959409351Z Please specify the command to run
```

My dockerfile content is as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "kestrel"]
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command you need to run is actually `dnx . kestrel` so try changing the ENTRYPOINT to be:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", ".", "kestrel"]
```